# Which is better scrolls or search_after in elasticsearch to simulate random pagination?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I want to randomly jump to a page of results from elasticsearch. There are three ways to paginate in elasticsearch:

- **from/size** - I can't use this because of the maximum depth limit of 10000.
- **scroll API** - I can use this but it has a cost of memory usage (keeping the search context alive) associated with it.
- **search_after** - I can also use this even it is less expensive than scrolls as it is stateless.

I know that anyway, Elasticsearch will sequentially read the data. Let's say if I wanted to get 99th page then elastic is going to read all 98 results to get the 99th result.

I can do one thing i.e. to reduce the data which I will sequentially get before the targeted data, in this case I will reduce the data returned for 98 pages and for the 99th one I will get the complete data.

My main question is "What if I don't have memory concerns then which approach would be faster to sequentially get 98 pages ?" (search_after or scrolls)

**If I use scrolls I will be clearing it after every usage.**

Answer (score 1):

*If you don't have memory concerns*, then the simplest option is to increase the index setting **index.max_result_window** from 10000 to the number you require.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But what I was looking for is "what is better search_after or scrolls" ? I did not intend to use from/size.

Answer (score -2):

Scroll API is best option for pagination of huge records. I have implemented scroll API pagination for more than 4 lakhs records.